# compile c++ in Emacs via tramp: Save password

Tags: emacs, ssh, passwords, tramp, plink

I am working with emacs in Win7 to develop C++ Code on a Linux server via SSH. Loading and Saving via Tramp (using plink) works well and the "Compile" command in emacs can also be used, but I need to reenter my password everytime.

Is there any way to keep the connection to the shell or save the password? Or do I have to do some authentication in plink?

Of course, I would be happy if you point me to a manual or other file which explains details about this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Investigate plink/putty's support for SSH public-key-based authentication.

Answer (score 3):

In short: you'll want to set up passwordless access to the machine using your system's SSH client.

By client:

- [Putty](http://www.dailyiteration.com/howto-passwordless-ssh-authentication-with-putty/)
- [OpenSSH](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152)

Further documentation on this case is available [here](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved by ssh keys.

All you have to do is create a DSA key pair and put public keys on your `~/.ssh` folder in file named as `authorized_keys`

On your local make sure you have `pageant.exe` running, and the key you created for your server loaded into it.

to test the configuration your can do

```
plink user@host
```